# How to set time check on login?

Tags: android

I want to set a time check of 30 Seconds. Basically what i want is i will call a webservice for login and after clicking the login button i want to check if i am not getting a status OK within 30 seconds i want so show a alert tha please try again. How to set this ?

Login button:

```
        logbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                SharedPreferences myPrefs = Login.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
                prefsEditor.putLong("starttime", start);
                prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

Here i want to check the difference Here:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = Login.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            time = myPrefs.getLong("starttime", System.currentTimeMillis());
if("ok".equalsIgnoreCase(status) && (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) > 3000)
{
    \\Code
}
else
{  
    Alert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start a new thread, which will be responsible for status checking. In that your new thread you can simply use sleep method and after 30 seconds of sleep - you will show a status to user. Check more info about threads in Java API.

Comment: By doing this it will automatically exceed 30 secs.

Comment: so why do you want to add a 30secs of interval? just try login, if it success - ok, if not - alert message. it does not change anything that 30secs interval. or do you want to avoid server timeouts ?

Comment: this is an example of HTTP POST:
[link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)[/link]
also if you want to set a time out DefaultHttpClient has a constructor, where you can set a timeout. short example:
        `HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT); 
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
`
and then you create a DefaultHttpClient object.

Comment: Yes this is an example of the SAME.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet

```
long startTime = 0;

logbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = Login.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putLong("starttime", start);
        prefsEditor.commit();
        startLoginThread();
 }


private void startLoginThread()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                if((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) > 30 * 1000)
                {
                    //show your allert
                }

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```